# npm ERR! reason: connect ETIMEDOUT

Tags: nodejs, windows, npm

Intentando utilizar 'npm' resulta en **error**. No estoy utilizando ninguna proxy de oficina o empresa, estoy en mi domicilio particular, y mi Sistema Operativo es Windows 11.

Al utilizar "npm i":

```
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.com/@xmldom/xmldom/-/xmldom-0.7.10.tgz failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700::6810:1123:80
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

Al utilizar "npm ping":

```
$ npm ping
npm notice PING http://registry.npmjs.com/
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.com/-/ping?write=true failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700::6810:1823:80
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

Al utilizar "npm run start" o "npx expo start":

```
FetchError: request to https://api.expo.dev/v2/version/latest failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700::6812:568:443
```

Lo que he intentado:

- Verificar si el Firewall impidiendo que me conecte, y desactivarlo tambien.
- Limpiar la cache
- Varias soluciones de GitHub y StackOverflow del siguiente tipo o variaciones:

```
npm config delete proxy
npm config delete http-proxy
npm config delete https-proxy
```

- Iniciar nuevo proyecto en otra carpeta.
- Reiniciar VS Code.
- Reiniciar PC.
- Activar/Desactivar VPN.
- Cambiar de conexión a internet.